# Providing API for communicating with a running application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, object, jailbreak

Basically I'm trying to find a solution to my issue with sharing an object. I've had a look at SpringBoard's implementation and it looks as if SpringBoard is providing a framework which can be used to retrieve **SBDisplay** objects (which are basically **CALayers**).

I know this specific issue is related to iPhones, but I also know that this is also used by a lot of Cocoa software. Could someone point out a way to copy such behaviour?

App 1 (Application launcher) :

- Launches client applications
- Has the main **CALayer** object
- Serves as the window server

App 2 (Client app) :

- Needs the main **CALayer** from App1 to render itself onto

*And again, just to reiterate - I am fully aware of AppStore policies. And yes, I am using a **jailbroken** device.*

Comment: How is this different from your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317724/an-example-of-pushing-and-retrieving-of-an-nsobjects-pointer-in-objc-from-shared

Comment: I am asking about different ways of implementing the same task. So the question isn't exactly the same.